# HttpWebRequest - Fake Javascript Enabled

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, web-scraping

Im trying to download a webpage in c# using:

```
var responseData = "";
var strUrl = this.QuerySelector(item, "a[class='url']").Attributes["href"].Value;

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strUrl);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
request.UserAgent = this.RefreshUserAgent();
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Cookies = request.CookieContainer.GetCookies(request.RequestUri);
var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
var responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding, true);

responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
responseReader.Close();
```

But the site keeps giving me the same code, enable JavaScript to continue.
I have already data checked with Fiddler - its just naviagates to itself again but I cannot get past this message:

```
Before you can move on - please enable JavaScript.
```

The site is Manta.com and this is my example page.
Any ideas..

http://www.manta.com/c/mrsywyl/leeds-automotive

Answer (score 3):

This is correct. `HttpWebRequest` just does a HTTP request. It has no support for JavaScript. If you want that behaviour try using the `WebBrowser` control or something like Awesomium.

Comment: Exactly. The server is expecting a request from the JavaScript, which is not executed by `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: So it must be possible to emulate? Some part of the request must be generated by the javascript

Comment: @AaronGibson: Yes. That's why he recommended using `WebBrowser`, or the Awesomium package, both of which will execute the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try faking UserAgent request header:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
```